# Executing Code on a local machine from an AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

For a university project I have created a chatbot that calls a lambda function written in Python.

```
import webbrowser
import boto3
import logging
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import json
def handler(event,callback):

function_type = event['currentIntent']['slots']['slotOne']
print('This went to the search')
webbrowser.open('www.google.com')
response = {
    "dialogAction": {
        "type": "Close",
        "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
        "message": {
          "contentType": "SSML",
          "content": "opening google now"
                },
            }
        }
    return response
```

I can send and receive information in this lambda fine but I am unable to have it open www.google.com using the `webbrowser` import. This works locally and I was wondering if there was a way to have my lambda trigger code saved locally on my machine, or have the code in my lambda be executed locally when called by my chatbot.

Comment: Is your Lambda function configured to connect to a VPC? If so, it does not have Internet access unless there is a NAT Gateway. If there is no VPC configuration, it should be able to reach the Internet. What error do you get?

Comment: To clarify, i get a response from the lambda fine my chatbot is connected to it and i can populate slots. My issue is that the webbrowser import doesnt seem to do anything and i assume this is because the lambda is not executed locally on the machine. Sorry for poor wording of my question im new to these technologies.

Comment: the logic of this code seems to work fine when ran locally it will open a browser with www.google.com

Comment: You can insert print statements to debug your code. As long as the Lambda function has `logs:*` permission, you can see the output in CloudWatch Logs. Or, if you run a test in the Lambda console, debug is provided on-screen.

Comment: thanks for your help @JohnRotenstein. I have been able to solve my issue. I did not realise that i could read the returned string value from the lambda response. I have solved my issue it was becasuse of my understanding and not because of a solution